# swiper , use slidesPerView with loop

Tags: reactjs, slider, swiper.js

hi i want to use swiper in react now i want to use autoplay and loop=true for my slider but when i use sliderPreview={3} or sliderPreview={4} the loop it's not working only work when my sliderPreview it's 1 but i want to show 3 or 4.

```
 <Swiper
      modules={[Autoplay, Pagination]}
      slidesPerView={3}
      spaceBetween={10}
      loop={true}
      autoplay={{
        delay: 1000,
      }}
      pagination={{ clickable: true }}
    >
      {blogPosts.map((post) => (
        <SwiperSlide className={styles.slider} key={post.id}>
          <div
            style={{
              background: `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),  url("${post.image}") no-repeat center center`,
              backgroundSize: "cover",
              width: "100%",
              height: "20rem",
            }}
          >
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
```